# Microtype gives wrong letterspacing in math mode

Tags: math-mode, classicthesis, microtype, letterspacing

Using the `\lsstyle` command gives wrong math latterspacing afterwards. I came upon this problem when using the `classicthesis` and putting math in a section (`microtype` is used there too). After the section is rendered, math letterspacing is wrong from then on.

**Minimal working example**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DeclareMathOperator{\MyOp}{MyVeryLargeOperator}

\begin{document}
Before: $\MyOp(1,2,3)$. % this is how it should be.

{\lsstyle $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$} % \lsstyle and math inside a group.

After: $\MyOp(1,2,3)$. % now math has wrong letterspacing.

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

Any ideas how to fix this? I would especially be interesting in a fix working with classicthesis. You can see the problem here:

```
\documentclass[pdfspacing]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diagonal}

\begin{document}
\section{Usual section works fine}

\[ \int f(x) \mathrm dx, \; \diag(a_1, \ldots, a_n), \; \ker(f) \]

\section{But some math in a title $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ messes it up}

\[ \int f(x) \mathrm dx, \; \diag(a_1, \ldots, a_n), \; \ker(f) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's a bug in `microtype`. Until the package is updated, a temporary fix would be to add

```
\makeatletter\let\glb@currsize\@empty\makeatother
```

after the `\lsstyle` and math inside a group, which forces the math fonts to be set up anew.

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in `microtype` v2.6.

Comment: I think that the fix in 2.6. is problematic (the change in `\MT@set@tr@codes`) see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316231/microtype-and-exscale-crashing-in-texlive-2016. Wouldn't it be better to add `\aftergroup\glb@settings` to the `\lsstyle` definition like e.g. `\mathversion` does? It seems to solve the problem too.