# microtype and exscale crashing in TeXLive-2016

Tags: microtype

I just installed TeXLive-2016 and noticed that microtype, more precisely, the command `\textls` and `exscale` crashes, whereas they work fine in TeXLive-2015. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{exscale}
\begin{document}
\textls[160]{$abc$}
\end{document}
```

What would be the reason behind this incompatibility?

Comment: The problem is clearly in what `exscale` adds to `\every@math@size`; not sure why it used to work and doesn't now.

Comment: @egreg: Imho it is a microtype problem. It seems to do some \global\let (\MT@glet) instead of \let now for \glb@currsize etc. But I'm not sure where exactly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I seem to remember that the local setting of `\glb@currsize` caused problems elsewhere: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291308/problem-with-microtypes-textls-and-math-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why math is used in a `\textls` context, but…

There is a difference between `microtype` version 2.6a (TL 2016)

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\lsstyle{%
  \not@math@alphabet\lsstyle\textls
  \MT@glet\glb@currsize\@empty
  \def\MT@feat{tr}%
  \let\MT@tracking\MT@set@tr@codes
  \selectfont
}
```

and version 2.5a (TL 2015)

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\lsstyle{%
  \not@math@alphabet\lsstyle\textls
  \let\glb@currsize\@empty
  \def\MT@feat{tr}%
  \let\MT@tracking\MT@set@tr@codes
  \selectfont
}
```

The code is in `microtype-pdftex.def` and in `microtype-luatex.def` (no `\textls` is defined with XeTeX).

There is no comment in the sources about the change from `\let` to `\global\let`, but it's what it should be done (see source2e). However, `exscale` does

```
\addto@hook\every@math@size{%
  \begingroup
     \setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{$($}\kern\z@}%
     \global\big@size 1.2\ht\z@
  \endgroup}
```

and we can see the problem: the math formula inside the group triggers setting the math sizes and the value of `\glb@currsize` is empty, causing `\every@math@size` to be called… Infinite loop.

The following patch might solve the problem, because `\textfont0` should already be set when the `\hbox` is built for measuring purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\edef\next{\the\every@math@size}
\patchcmd\next{\hbox{$($}}{\hbox{\the\textfont\z@(}}{}{}
\every@math@size=\expandafter{\next}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($

{\Large$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($}

\textls[160]{$abc$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the empty \glb@currsize alone is the problem. \mathversion sets it to empty too, and excale doesn't break. Resetting the older lsstyle definition doesn't help. And `\lsstyle \gdef\glb@currsize{10} $abc$` fails too (but with a different error).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem, I believe, is in typesetting the test formula in `\every@math@size`, which is not done by `\mathversion`. However, something else should be done, because `\glb@currsize` turns out to be empty.

Comment: The problem is in the definition of `\MT@set@tr@codes`. At the end a line has been added that resets `\glb@currsize` (`\MT@glet\noexpand\glb@currsize\noexpand\@empty`}. When I remove this the example compiles again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The code was added as a fix for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187655/microtype-gives-wrong-letterspacing-in-math-mode

Comment: shouldn't microtype in \lsstyle use `\aftergroup\glb@settings` (like mathversion) to avoid this bug instead of the code in `\MT@set@tr@codes`? Seems to work fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Possibly, but the problem here is how to make `microtype` and `exscale` go along.

Comment: Well if I remove the line from \MT@set@tr@codes and add \aftergroup\glb@settings to \lsstyle their is no problem -- neither here nor with the other question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for providing this fix, which is far better than what I had come up with (simply disabling `microtype` in `\every@math@size` -- math font setup will probably never cease to be a miracle to me). I'll fix this with the next version.