# How to limit scope of microtype's letterspacing command \textls to non-math environment?

Tags: math-mode, microtype, letterspacing, definition, scoping

Package [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype?lang=en) has the command `\textls` to manipulate letterspacing in an *ad hoc* manner. While its use is usually frowned upon by typographists, according to [`microtype`'s user manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) (p 23 footnote), it has *some* appropriate uses for local emphasis.

Applying `\textls` in a naïve manner leads to undesirable consequences when mixed with mathematical content. It is the **purpose of this question** to get a modified command `\myTextls` which works *syntactically and semantically* exactly like `\textls` *but* leaves math mode untouched. Something like this is in play for the usual `\textsl` (notice the swapping of ‘l’ and ‘s’). See below.

**Here is an output of an MWE:**

[image: Output of MWE. \textls (and others)]

The spacing inside `{1, 2}` in row 2 is something like `{ 1, 2 }` instead of `{1, 2}` in rows 1 and 3.

*Note*. When I say ‘should’, of course, I mean simply that it is what *I* desire, nothing more. The slanted `textsl` is only brought out for *analogy of output*, I do not mean it to say anything about *analogy of implementation* which will likely be (very) different. By ‘splitting...is not desirable’ I refer only to *manual* splitting.

**Code for MWE:** // Run with Overleaf's version `2021/03/14 v2.8c` for `microtype`. Duplicated with my local distribution and version `2022/06/23 v3.0f` //

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}

%definition of \myTextls

\begin{document}

\textsl{1. [textsl] This should only affect text, not \( \{ 1, 2 \} \) mathematics. And \textit{does}!}

\textls{2. [textls] This should only affect text, not \( \{ 1, 2 \} \) mathematics. But \textit{doesn't}!}

\textls{3. [textls twice] Splitting up works} \( \{ 1, 2 \} \)  \textls{but is not desirable.}

%\myTextls{4. [myTextls] This should only affect text, not \( \{ 1, 2 \} \) mathematics. It \textit{does(n't)} work!}

\end{document}
```

---

**Similar questions**

There are two similar questions on this site which are not duplicates AFAIKT.

- [Problem with microtype's `\textls` and math mode [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291308/116907) – this is closed as a duplicate of the question below
- [Microtype gives wrong letterspacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187655/116907) – discusses instead a bug for earlier versions of `microtype` now fixed (in v2.6). Trying to alter the earlier, [pre-fix solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188583/116907) to this case proved unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that microtype isn't designed to distinguish between math mode and text mode (or more generally, isn't aware of the context in which a font selection occurs). For the case at hand, you could easily solve this if you would be willing to change the default text encoding to T1, because this would then leave OT1 for math only:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\SetTracking
  [ name = nomath, load = default ]
  { encoding = {OT1,OMS,OML,OMX} }
  { 0 }
```

If you don't want to change the encoding of your document, you could alternatively patch microtype to have it ignore fonts in math mode:

```
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\MT@set@tr@codes{\ifmmode\MT@set@tr@zero\else}{}{}
\apptocmd\MT@set@tr@codes{\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

(`\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` are from the `etoolbox` package, which `microtype` loads anyway)

In both solutions, you'd just use `\textls`.

---

As for the more general case of ignoring the contents of certain commands inside `\textls`, you could use the `\lslig` command (which is originally meant to keep ligatures in letterspaced text, but also works for longer pieces of text, including font changes):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\myemph[1]{\emph{\lslig{#1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you. While I do not personally need it and it is a bit of a tangent, is it possible to have `\textls` ignore something like `\emph`?

Comment: @LinearChristmas Do you mean to ignore italic fonts (which would go in the direction of solution 1 above), or the command `\emph` itself (and if the latter, what about nested emphasis?) Or do you actually have a more general problem in mind?

Comment: (1/2) I apologise for my absence. Your answer has been accepted and the bounty awarded just in time. || The situation in mind was as follows. 1. Someone defines their own formatting command `\myFormattingCommand{<content>}`. 2. Assume that for this type of formatting, it would make sense for `\textls` to not apply to `\myFormattingCommand`. 3. Would it be possible for `microtype` to ignore content inside `\myFormattingCommand` simply by seeing `\myFormattingCommand` pop up in code somewhere?

Comment: (2/2) The command `\emph` was meant as a concrete example of `\myFormattingCommand`. Your counterpoint on nested `\emph`'s is very much accepted. So it might be that perhaps `textls` should ignore `\myFormattingCommand`, but not when it is nested inside another `\myFormattingCommand`, and any pattern onwards. This makes it a lot more difficult of a problem than I had intended, so it is probably best discussed in a new question altogether. I would not expect you to answer it here, especially the nested variant (if even practically feasible).

Comment: @LinearChristmas Thanks :-) I've added some remarks about the general case.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!