# Bad math kerning in classicthesis if math is in the chapter title

Tags: chapters, classicthesis, kerning

With `classicthesis` as in the example-bundle given by [Miede](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads/).

I **only** add some math to one of the chapter-titles and some math (shown below) to the body text. When math in the title of the chapter is present, I get a bad math-kerning in the whole text of the title-page of that chapter. How to correct that?

See the differences:

With math:
[image]

As the text in the body should be:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{
pdfspacing,
                     subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}        
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some math in the title $X^2$}\label{ch:introduction}

Bad kerning $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and errors while referring to 
\begin{equation}
 a\cdot 0 = 0 \label{wow} 
\end{equation}
in another chapter-title.
\appendix

\chapter{Proof of formula \ref{wow}}\label{ch:second}

%*******************************************************
\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

**Solution which causes more problems**

I can comment `pdfspacing` and get rid of the bad kerning. But then it  conflicts with references in the chapter titles that I had and cannot modify (hyperref in some appendix section). Hence, I'd like to avoid prevent `pdfspacing` from loading.

Comment: MWE please.....

Comment: How are you compiling? I tried with pdflatex and don't see any difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAzVO.png

Comment: @samcarter if you refer to the first two pictures, pdflatex and I keep seeing the difference according to whether math is in the title or not (while `pdfspacing` is loaded). If it is with the addition of the code, it doesn't even generate a pdf, for instance, if I comment the pdfspacing line and compile.

Comment: @c.p. mmm, I don't get any difference with or without `pdfspacing`. Which version of pdflatex do you use? I tried with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)

Comment: Probably an old version of `microtype`, which had [a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187655/7674) with letterspacing and math fonts. Try updating.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my TeX Live `15, and/or try the solution by the answer linked by Robert.

Comment: Any news here? Did an upgrade help?